# django related manager - get specific data

Tags: python, django, django-related-manager

I am trying to get rate of the user who has written the comment.

this is the scenario:

I hold the comment about Something in my hand, I hold the user in my hand who wrote this comment Something. Now I need to know the rate which is given by the user to this Something.

these are my models:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
  of_user_r = models.ForeignKey(User)
  of_something_r = models.ForeignKey(Something)
  rate = models.IntegerField()

class Comment(models.Model):
  of_user_c = models.ForeignKey(User)
  of_something_c = models.ForeignKey(Something)
```

i did: `{{comment.of_user_c.of_user_r.rate}}`, but I getting nothing in template.
this is the vusual:

[image]

I need the rate of this Something which is given by this User.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your attempt doesn't work because the relationship from User to Rate is backwards. This means you can't do that query directly in the template: you'd need a model method or a template filter that accepts arguments. The basic query syntax would be:

```
Rate.objects.filter(user=comment.user)
```